# Поиск по XPATH в строке (Не в XML) C#

Tags: c#, строки, xpath

На входе есть строка

string txt = "Какой-то html текст"

Есть ли способ искать в нем c помощью XPATH?

Comment: Html Agility Pack

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Решил с помощью следующего шаблона кода.



    string txt = "html document";
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(txt);
    var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//XPATH").ToArray(); for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; 
    i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(items[i].OuterHtml);
    }